# Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`

Tags: flutter, mockito

I am trying to test my catch in my signInAnonyymous() function.  Yet, I am constantly getting the error stated in the title.

Here is my Mocked Auth class (edited for brevity):

```
class MockFirebaseAuth extends Mock implements FirebaseAuth {
  final bool signedIn;
  final bool isEmployee;

  MockFirebaseAuth({this.isEmployee = false, this.signedIn = false});

  @override
  Future<UserCredential> signInAnonymously() async {
  return MockUserCredential(isAnonymous: true);
  }
}
```

And, this is my test:

```
group('Sign-In-Anonymously', () {
setUp(() {
  mockFunctions = MockFirebaseFunctions();
  mockAuth = MockFirebaseAuth();
  mockCrashltyics = MockCrashlytics();
  mockFirestore = MockFirebaseFirestore();
  authRemoteService = AuthServiceFirebase(
    crashlytics: mockCrashltyics,
    firestoreService: mockFirestore,
    functions: mockFunctions,
    service: mockAuth,
  );
  authProvider = AuthProvider(authRemoteService);
});

test(
    'Should return a null AuthUser and non-null errorMessage on exception thrown',
    () async {
  when(mockAuth.signInAnonymously())
      .thenThrow(MockFirebaseAuthException('message', 'code'));
  //act
  await authProvider.signInAnonymously();
  //assert
  expect(authProvider.authUser, isNull);
  expect(authProvider.errorMessage, isNotNull);
});
});
```

I have researched and tried so many different ways and still can't test my catch.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to use 'when', you can't override the method in the mock. You need to provide an answer from the "thenAnswer".

Comment: Now that error message makes sense.  So, how would I test my exception catches using the firestore sdk in flutter?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking? I am assuming .thenThrow would let you test any try\catch clauses that are wrapping FireStore queries.

Comment: I figured it out. Ty.

Comment: @ScottGodfrey What was the solution you figured out or approach you used to catch the exception?

Comment: @blazebnayak Back then, I had to mock out every class of every method in Firebase I had to test.  So, I had to create MockDocumentReference, MockQuerySnapshot, etc.

Comment: Now, Mockito has a generator that will create all the necessary mocks for you.